# Not able to extract my mails to my desktop using IMAP

Tags: g1ant

I have been trying to extract all my emails from my gmail account and download it by addressing a path and storing it in my desktop. Even though there is smooth execution, none of my mails are getting stored in the desktop to the path that is defined. Can someone help me out with this?
Here is the picture of my code:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5yyQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code and you'll notice that there's another command that needs to be used in order to extract the emails from the account.

[Code Image in G1ANT Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyyNy.png)

I hope this helps.